# How to update xml using value from a sql query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, xml

I have a table with an XML column. I need to insert various nodes and then set those nodes using values from a sub-query.

Setup:

```
use tempdb

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Sites](
    [SiteID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SiteInfo] [xml] NULL,
    [InVal] Varchar(50) NULL)

insert into [dbo].[Sites] ([InVal]) select 'ABC' union select 'DEF' union  select 'GHI'

update [dbo].[Sites] SET [SiteInfo] = '<SiteInfo />'

update [dbo].[Sites] SET [SiteInfo].modify('insert <SiteID/> into (/SiteInfo[1])')
```

Here is my update in it's most simple form.

```
update Sites SET [SiteInfo].modify('replace value of (/SiteInfo/@SiteID)[1] with sql:column("InVal")')
```

I have tried with both singleton and non singleton nodes

The end result should preferably not be a singleton. i.e something like:

```
<SiteInfo>
  <SiteID>ABC</SiteID>
</SiteInfo>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got nothing to replace in `<SiteID/>`. Try and use an `insert` instead:

```
update Sites SET [SiteInfo].modify('insert text{sql:column("InVal")} as first into (/SiteInfo/SiteID)[1]');
```

Comment: Can you insert the node and text at the same time?

Comment: @Peter: Yes. `update [dbo].[Sites] SET [SiteInfo].modify('insert <SiteID>123</SiteID> into (/SiteInfo[1])') `

Comment: Eureka! update [dbo].[Sites] SET [SiteInfo].modify('insert <SiteID>text{sql:column("InVal")}</SiteID> into (/SiteInfo[1])')